# Redirect to a different web page based on date

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I would prefer to use Javascript for this, but any language is fine.

I am redesigning my web page. It will be released at 12:00am on July 31. I have put both versions of the site into different directories. I want this code on the home page to redirect the user to the correct page based on the date.

Example: User logs on at 5:00pm on June 29 --> Redirected to /current. User logs in at 1:00pm on August 1 --> Redirected to /new.

Comment: Do you want PHP or Javascript solution? You tagged your question for both.

Comment: Why mess with URI structure and such.  You are probably better off having multiple virtual hosts and making a DNS cutover or web server config change at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following javascript you can do this.

```
// For todays date;
Date.prototype.today = function () { 
return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"/"+(((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ this.getFullYear();
}

if((new Date().today()) >= "01/08/2014")
{
 location.href ="new location url";
}
else
 {
 location.href="current location url";
}
```

Comment: Sorry im kinda a noob at javascript, does this need jQuery library?

Comment: No. this is pure javascript.

Comment: You don't want a javascript solution for this. You are going to be subject to different behavior based on end user's timezone. Not to mention you are also relying on client-side behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`if (time() < strtotime("06/29/2014 5:00PM"))
{
    //redirect to current
    header("Location : http://website.com/current");
    exit;
}
    elseif(time() > strtotime("01/08/2014 1:00PM")){

    //redirect to new
    header("Location : http://website.com/new");
    exit;
}`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: time is not defined